# Spring Boot 2 Migration from weblogic legacy applicaiton

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, weblogic

What could be possible reason for getting below error:

java.rmi.RemoteException: weblogic.utils.collections.ConcurrentHashMap.access$000(Lweblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap;)[Lweblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap$Entry;; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.utils.collections.ConcurrentHashMap.access$000(Lweblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap;)[Lweblogic/utils/collections/ConcurrentHashMap$Entry;

The application is calling weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.StubImpl.class _invoke method

Comment: Are you migrating from Weblogic to Tomcat?  Are you including Weblogic libraries with your war file?

Comment: yes I have added wlfulclient as a dependency

Comment: I resolved that by adding following dependency:
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
   <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.2-0</version>
  </dependency>